IC 4017 output modification to pulse when released button?
Normally working with 3 output LED,

when press button in first time LED1 on LED2 and LED3 off
then released button in first time LED1 still on LED2 and LED3 still off.
When press button in secend time LED1 off LED2 on LED3 off
then released button in secend time LED1 still off LED2 still on LED3 still off.
When press button in third time LED1 off LED2 off LED3 on
then released button in third time LED1 still off LED2 still offLED3 still on.

This function I make it working OK.
But i want to modification output to this function.

when press button in first time LED1 on LED2 and LED3 off
then released button in first time all LED off
When press button in second time LED1 off LED2 on LED3 off
then released button in second time all LED off
When press button in third time LED1 off LED2 off LED3 on
then released button in third time all LED off

How can I do with 4017 or I have to use another IC. Thank you.

Please post your schematic.

Timing diagrams are so much better than words!
           __    __    __    __   
button: __|  |__|  |__|  |__|  |__
           _____
Output1:__|     |_________________
                 _____
Output2:________|     |___________
                       _____
Output3:______________|     |_____

Figure 1. What you've got.
           __    __    __    __   
button: __|  |__|  |__|  |__|  |__

trigger:__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__
           __
Output1:__|  |____________________
                 __
Output3:________|  |______________
                       __
Output5:______________|  |________

Figure 1. What you want.
You need to modify your button signal so that it gives a pulse on both the rising edge and falling edge. Then you just use outputs 1, 3 and 5.
